# If call to one api fails call another api, if both fail return an error

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, observable

I'm trying to do the following pseudo code in Angular. For getData1() i'm using a pipe and map but when making the same call to getData2() it's not letting me call map. I also need to be able to unit test getData() this but it seems complex to test nested calls

```
let data = '';

when called on init
  getData().subscribe(res=>{this.data = res.data})


getData():Observable{
  Make request to getData1()
    if getData1() success
      return response
    () => { // call this if getData1() fails
      if http get to third party api fails (e.g. its down)
        Make request to getData2()
          if getData2() success
            return response
    }
  If both fail
    send error to be handled by another service
}

getData1(): Observable<TestData1Res> {
 return http.get(external url 1);
}
getData2(): Observable<TestData2Res>  {
 return http.get(external url 2);
}
```

How do I stop the response in the main method call subscribe from erroring with 'Property 'testData' does not exist on type 'TestData1Res| TestData2Res', where only TestData2Res contains property 'testData' The response from both apis will have different properties

e.g
.subscribe(
(res) => {
if (res.testData) { << this errors with that msg
}
}

Comment: Is the response structure the same, or different for each API?

Comment: You can use RxJs `catchError` operator for a much cleaner solution. The code isn't very readable to be honest, but I hope my comment helps you. You make the first request with the pipe `catchError`. Inside the catchError you perform the second request. The subscribe will return the first if it works, the second if the first throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/error-handling-by-sequential-call-pn0nt?file=/src/index.ts)
You can simply use `catchError` and return the second call when first fails and return response in subscribe, if both calls fails it will enter the error of subscribe.

```
// a call that always passes
let fakeCall = (d = 10) => of(d);

// a call always fails
let fakeError = (e = 10) => throwError(new Error('fake error!: ' +  e));

// here it will make first call only and ignore second call
fakeCall(10).pipe(catchError(c => fakeCall(20)))
.subscribe((r) => console.log('response', r), 
e => console.log('error',e)); 
// repsponse 10

// here it will make first call but not second so second error has not impact
fakeCall(10).pipe(catchError(c => fakeError(20)))
 .subscribe(
   (r) => console.log('response', r), 
   e => console.log('error',e)); 
   // response 10

// here the it will make second call and return response of second call
   fakeError(10).pipe(catchError(c => fakeCall(20)))
.subscribe(
  (r) => console.log('response', r), 
  (e) => console.log('error',e)); 
  // response 20


fakeError(10).pipe(catchError(c => fakeError(20)))
.subscribe(
(r) => console.log('response', r), 
(e) => console.log('error',e)); 
// error 20
```